# Fill listbox with items in database whose date matches textbox input

Tags: c#, textbox, listbox

I have a search form and I want to search entries by date. The date will be entered in a textbox or a date time picker control. All the entries that match this date should be filled into the listbox.

Please can anyone help: how is this possible?

Comment: also, want on earth is this in? WinForms? WPF? Asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry vivek - but my answer is "try writing it!"

If you are that unsure about where to start, then you can also try:

- reading some winforms date time picker tutorials - e.g http://cplus.about.com/od/learnc/ss/adv_winforms.htm

and then try:

- post a better explanation,
- post some sample code,
- post some details about what you've already tried,